# On iPad/iBooks: XHTML code for opening/linking to another app within ebook?

Tags: ipad, xhtml, epub

My question applies to the iBook app for the iPad.

The goal is to be able to open another app on the iPad from within the text of an ebook.

What code should be inserted into an EPUB's XHTML file to create a direct link to another app on the iPad?

Answer (score 3):

Using a **URL scheme** you can open other applications.

URL schemes used by the default applications are listed at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to use a UIDocumentInteractionController. Don't believe it can be done using XHTML. Have a look at these guides: [Class API](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html) [Apple iPad Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009370-CH6-SW10)

basically you will be able to open a menu with the option to launch the file (direct link if you want) in any of the apps installed that are registered to support that type of file. Good luck.